# How long does it take for the speed of the train to decrease to $1~\text{m/s}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Here's the full problem:

> *The speed of a train coasting on a level track satisfies the differential equation $\mathrm{d}V/\mathrm{d}t = kv^2$. The initial speed of the train is $v(0)=10~\text{m/s}$ and the speed is decreasing at the rate of $-1~\text{m/s}^2$ when $v=5~\text{m/s}$. How long does it take for the speed of the train to decrease to $1~\text{m/s}$? Under this model, when does the train stop?*

I'm very bad with word problems and have been struggling quite a bit. I'd go to my school's tutoring center but currently we are on labor day vacation. -_-

EDIT 1: I've attempted it a few times and here's my answer:
$vknot=10~\text{m/s}, v=5~\text{m/s}, a=-1~\text{m/s}^2$

I found $k = -1/25$ and the proceeded to integrate the $\mathrm{d}V/\mathrm{d}t = kv^2$. The equation I then got was $v=kv^2t + vknot$ and plugged all my conditions in. My answer was $t=5~\text{s}$. I have no idea if I am correct as word problems always throw me off.

EDIT 2: I found k=-1/25 by plugging into the dV/dt equation. dV/dt is the same as acceleration and it's stated that our acceleration is -1m/s^2, leading to this:
$-1 = k(5)^2$  ===> $-1 = 25k$ ===> $-1/25 = k$. I don't know if this was valid to do, but I wasn't sure how to approach so made the assumption that it was valid.

EDIT 3: After realizing the error with my integration, after integrating I got the formula $v=v(vknot)kt + vknot$. Time was then t=2.5 after plugging in my information. Now I just don't know how to tell when the train stops...

Comment: I've added the homework tag. Please use that tag on homework questions.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, Ben. I will now do so in the future.

Comment: How did you solve that differential equation? And how did you get k=-0.04? Oh and is it $dv/dt$ or is $V$ something different?

Comment: Disregard the question about k, I got that. But how did you get that equation after integration?

Comment: The problem here is with your equation after you integrated it ;) Try separating the variables :)

Comment: Thank you, my friend! As I was trying to write out how I got what I did with transposing the dt to the right side, I realized I should have transposed the $v^2$ as well!

Comment: Yep ;) That's the thing I wanted to point to you. You should get the correct equation for v(t) now :) You can even try to plot the function in Mathematica or Sage :)

Comment: Think i figured out the proper time. Appreciate the help my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll help with the integration, since that's obviously your weak point.

You have:

$\frac{dv}{dt}=k v^2$

Where $v\equiv v(t)$, so to solve the above differential equation, you need to separate the variables - all the $v$ parts on one side, and all the $t$ parts on the other

$\frac{dv}{v^2}=k dt$

This was probably the confusing part (I think that was confusing for me too when I was in my 1st year of Uni and when I had no clue to what DE were, so don't bring yourself down : ) )

Now you can safely integrate both sides. We'll set $v(0)\equiv v_0$ for shorthand notation:

$\int\limits_{v_0}^{v}\frac{dv'}{v\ '^2}=k\int\limits_{0}^{t}dt'$

After integration you have:

$-\left.\frac{1}{v'}\right|_{v_0}^v=k t'\left.\right|_0^t$

That is after you put limits in:

$-\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{v_0}=kt\Rightarrow v(t)=\frac{10}{1-10 kt}$

Now you can put $k$ in and try to graph it, and solve your problem :)

Comment: I'm great at integration I'm just terrible at word problems. Give me integrals, I can do them all day. Give me a word problem and everything goes to hell. I'm taking physics for the first time this semester so I'm going to be getting much better. Thank you for the help

Comment: Ok, but brush up on differential equations, since you'll see those more often now ;)
Glad I could help :)